# In Visual Studio, is there a way to word-wrap ONLY comments?

Tags: visual-studio, comments

I've looked, but it doesn't look like you can apply specific formatting to just comments.

Comment: Barring this, is there a keyboard shortcut for turning word-wrap on and off quickly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is an Add-In which will automatically format your comments to a given width (as a side feature).

It is [HyperAddIn](http://hyperaddin.codeplex.com/Wikipage) - the main feature of which is allowing you to create 'hyperlinks' to other places in your code within comments, like this:

```
// The other half of this logic is in code:ComponentManager.Initialise()
```

With HyperAddIn installed, the `code:ComponentManager.Initialise()` becomes a clickable link.

I have it installed, it works OK, but I must admit that most of the time I don't have the comment formatting switched on.

Answer (score 4):

No. 
The shortcut is Ctrl+E, Ctrl+W.

There would be one trick how to format the comments. Write your own code snippet for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

As I have not found anything suitable so far, I use **Vim**. I set *Open in &Vim* as an external tool command, so I can just press `Alt+T,V` to open the current file in it. In Vim, I find the comment (press `/` for incremental search), select it (`Shift+V` selects whole line) and `gq` command formats the selected text. Finally, `:wq` and I am back in Visual Studio.

Hopefully, some simple extension appears in future or [VsVim](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329/) will get this feature.

Comment: I love this solution! I use VsVim, most of the time, but I often want to drop into Vim for the full experience. This gives me the ability to do just that with ease. I wish I could up-vote this answer another time.

Answer (score 3):

[CodeMaid's page](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496?SRC=VSIDE) lists re-flowing comments among its many code-beautification features.

Answer (score 1):

The free [AtomeerUtils](http://www.atomineerutils.com/products.php) addin mentions such a feature:

> - Word-wrap the text in a block comment.

I have not tried it.

Comment: Note this is not a free product, however a 30 day trial is available.

Answer (score -3):

You can extend VS 2010 to do this
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ToDoGlyphFactory

Answer (score -4):

It may not answer the question directly, but, instead of:

```
//Writing a really really long comment on one line that should probably be broken up into multiple lines anyhow
```

Why don't you:

```
//Break your comments up into multiple lines so that
//you don't need to worry about them wrapping?
```

Also, I don't like long lines of code - break them up across multiple lines so it's easier to read. All a matter of preference I know, but if you have to scroll horizontally to see all the code, it's a good sign it needs formatting better IMO.

Comment: This is an epic pain to manage.  If you add to or elaborate on your comment, you have to go back and fix all the hard line breaks you added.

Comment: @Deane: I don't know, I've used this method for over 10 years and it's been fine. Of course, it's anecdotal, but I do think you can trivially follow this approach (and it's "scalable" to any editor :P)

Comment: 10yrs on and this approach still works perfectly for me.

Comment: This is great, except when it's your coworkers' code -_-

Comment: I don’t agree sorry. With code formatters there’s really no issue in this approach. In JavaScript/Go (primary languages for me) the code is formatted on every save and multi line comments like this have no negative impact.